# Using purrr::walk() and ifelse to produce ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have a dataframe with one row per individual. The columns are an outcome variable and then a bunch of potential predictors of that outcome. As a preliminary step of my data analysis I want to visualize each predictor variable and its association with the outcome using ggplot. I'd like a histogram for continuous variables and a bar plot for categorical.

My attempt is

```
numeric <- c(0,1.1,2.4,3.1,4.0,5.9,4.2,3.3,2.2,1.1)
categorical <- as.factor(c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no"))
outcome <- as.factor(c("alive","dead","alive","dead","alive","dead","alive","dead","alive","dead"))
df <- data.frame(num = numeric, cat = categorical, outcome = outcome)
predictors <- c("num", "cat")
predictors %>%
    walk(print(ggplot(df, aes(x=., fill=outcome)) +
    {ifelse(class(.) == "factor", geom_bar(position="fill"), geom_histogram(position="fill", bins=10))}))
```

But I get the error

```
Error in rep(no, length.out = length(ans)): attempt to replicate an object of type 'environment'
Traceback:

1. predictors %>% walk(print(ggplot(df, aes(x = ., fill = outcome)) + 
 .     {
 .         ifelse(class(.) == "factor", geom_bar(position = "fill"), 
 .             geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 10))
 .     }))
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. walk(., print(ggplot(df, aes(x = ., fill = outcome)) + {
 .     ifelse(class(.) == "factor", geom_bar(position = "fill"), 
 .         geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 10))
 . }))
10. map(.x, .f, ...)
11. as_mapper(.f, ...)
12. print(ggplot(df, aes(x = ., fill = outcome)) + {
  .     ifelse(class(.) == "factor", geom_bar(position = "fill"), 
  .         geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 10))
  . })
13. ifelse(class(.) == "factor", geom_bar(position = "fill"), geom_histogram(position = "fill", 
  .     bins = 10))   # at line 9 of file <text>
```

I expect this code two produce two plots
[image: numeric plot]
[image: categorical plot]

My actual dataset has >20 predictors, so I'd like a nice way to produce 20+ ggplots and ideally keep it in a pipeline format like this so I can add additional steps once I get the plots working.

Comment: when walking over your predictors vector, the `class(.)` will always be character. Do you mean to refer to that column of your df? ie `class(df[[.]])`. Secondly, `ifelse` can not be used to return this type of objects afaik, better use standard `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way passing `predictors` columns to `map` and create a list of plots based on the `class` of the column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

p1 <- map(predictors, function(p) if (class(df[[p]]) == "factor") 
      ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(p), fill=outcome)) + geom_bar(position="fill")
      else
      ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(p), fill=outcome)) + 
                 geom_histogram(position="fill", bins=10))

p1[[1]]
```

[image]

```
p1[[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: @pgcudahy Instead of `!!sym(p)` if we just use `p` as  `predictors` are characters  it would mean running `ggplot(df, aes(x="num", fill=outcome)) + geom_histogram(position="fill", bins=10)` for `num` column. where `x` in `aes` is evaluated to string "num" instead we want it to be column `num`. `sym` convert the character to symbol and `!!` (read as bang bang) evaluates it to current context in the dataframe so that it works as intended.